# Outlook email client : pointer-events:none

Tags: html, css

I want to disable event of element inside the div.It is possible through  `pointer-events:none` css property. If I use this CSS property to send email using java program, it is not supported in Outlook/Gmail.

is there any other way to disable event of elements inside div?

Comment: Just place another element over your div to *disable* it

Comment: what do you mean. could you elaborate please

Comment: `position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0`

Comment: it is not working

Comment: Don't forget to set background to transparent image

Comment: Visiting this after long 4 years.... @bNd could you please share if you got any workaround this ? I wan to use "pointer-events:none" as inline style, but this is getting stripped in outlook

Comment: Anyone knows how to prevent outlook from interpreting text separated by "." as anchor tag/link ? Ex if text read "Name1.Name2.Name3", outlook renders it in anchor tag

Answer (score 2):

You may use `z-index` property. Something like this:

```
.container {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 0;
   background: none;
}
.container > * {
   position: relative;
   z-index: -1;
}
```

This makes content visible, but not clickable, because parent div is on top layer.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eL1omuz1/)