# In email template, mail automatically removes pointer-events: none in class

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, html-email

As i am working in email templates, i added a class like this in my email template.

```
img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

but when I open the mail in the inbox. It automatically removes pointer-events in the css class.

```
img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

like this. Is there any solution or workaround for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outlook email client : pointer-events:none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848979/outlook-email-client-pointer-eventsnone)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

As it seems the pointers-events property is not supported, you may use z-index property. Something like this:

```
.container {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 0;
   background: none;
}
.container > * {
   position: relative;
   z-index: -1;
}
```

This makes content visible, but not clickable, because parent div is on top layer.

Copied answer from here: stackoverflow.com/a/39851786/34092

Comment: yeah thanks for your answer. but i could able to do that by applying it as background image. which makes it as  non-clickable. anyways I think your answer suits more than mine.

Comment: Please be explicit that this is a straight copy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/39851786/34092 .

Comment: I straight copied. @mjwills